# Node.js and Modules require. Objects are not assigned by reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm writing this question after 2 days of total struggling during which I couldn't find a solution but also couldn't find an explanation of why this code is not working.

I will report a super simplified simulation of my code.

I have 5 Node.js files:

```
1) server.js -> Is the main file used to start the server
2) globalVars.js -> Is where all the server "global" objects are stored.
3) globalFunctions.js -> Is where all "general" functions are stored to be used by all other modules
4) helloManager.js -> Example file which contains some standard function used by the server
5) aspect.js -> Same as helloManager.js
```

```js
    //server.js
        
    //Loading the globalVars file. All objects are passed by reference so I use this to store the global variables
    var globalVars = require("./globalVars.js");
    
    //Assigning to the respective global object all the functions exported from other modules
    globalVars.Modules.globalFunctions = require("./globalFunctions.js");
    globalVars.Modules.aspect = require("./aspect.js");
    globalVars.Modules.helloManager = require("./helloManager.js");
    //After this point, the objects in globalVars.js will be populated with the respective functions exported from the files
    
    //A timeout just to be sure it is not a problem of timing? (Well, it is not...)
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(globalVars.Modules.helloManager.helloOutput());
    }, 2000);
    /*
    Console will throw the following error:
    ../globalFunctions.js:6
        return "MR. " + aspect.getAspect();
                                ^
    TypeError: aspect.getAspect is not a function
    */
```

```js
    //globalVars.js
    
    //Objects that will be populated with the functions inside other modules
    module.exports.Modules = {
        aspect: {},
        helloManager: {},
        globalFunctions: {}
    };
```

```js
    //helloManager.js
    var globalVars = require("./globalVars.js");
    var { globalFunctions } = globalVars.Modules;    
    module.exports.helloOutput = function(){
        return "hello " + globalFunctions.getHumanData();
    };
```

```js
    //aspect.js
        
    module.exports.getAspect = function(){
        return "human";
    };
```

```js
    //globalFunctions.js
        
    var globalVars = require("./globalVars.js");
    var { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;
        
    module.exports.getHumanData = function(){
        return "MR. " + aspect.getAspect();
    };
```

Please don't answer me to put everything in the same file, because my code is way more complicated to report so here I'm posting this very simple simulation.

I know that objects are assigned by reference and so if all modules get the variables from "globalVars" they works kinda like "global".

The problem is when in **globalFunctions.js** I load

```js
    var { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;
```

Since in *server.js* the module *aspect.js* is not loaded yet, it will be an empty object.
But I'm expecting that

```js
    var { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;
```

is getting the reference of **globalVars** and not a copy, so when **server.js** finishes loading all the modules, the variabile **aspect** inside **globalVars.Modules** will point to the correct object and so it would find the function I need!

Infact the console.log inside *server.js* is executed after all modules have been loaded for this exact reason.

Does anyone know what is the reason of this problem and how could I solve it?
Thank to everyone who will help!

Comment: Hi @Teoz, please don't publish your question when it's unfinished, or there might be people already downvoting you. (ps: wasn't me)

Comment: I'm sorry but I was getting mad because it was not letting me publish the post. I made it step by step...

Comment: You're right about everything you say. But deconstruction. When you deconstruct you get a reference to `null`, which is the value of aspect at that moment and it will never ever point to anything else.

Comment: *"I know that objects are passed by reference"* "Pass by reference" has a specific meaning in programming related to passing references **to variables** (not objects). JavaScript doesn't have pass by reference. What you're referring to there is that when you assign a variable referencing an object to another variable, you get a copy of the reference, not a copy of the object.

Comment: Have you tried `return "MR. " + globalVars.Modules.aspect.getAspect();`? It's not ideal but the alternative would be using a callback or promise to set the value of `aspect` when it is known.

Comment: PabloRecalde I have tried also with **var aspect = globalVars.Modules.aspect;** instead of decostruction, but it doesn't work anyway.
@GOTO0 In that way it works, but I really can't understand why! Do you have any clue?
T.J.Crowder I changed in "Objects are assigned by reference", is that more correct?

Comment: If it were me, instead of `var { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;` I would write `var aspect = require('./aspect')`.  Why aren't you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's happening

It's an issue of what it means to do `const { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;` (which is the same as `const aspect = globalVars.Modules.aspect;`). That is, it's a matter of assignment semantics.

Let's look at a simpler example, then we can see hot it applies to what you're doing. Assume you have:

```
let a = {/*original object*/};
```

When you do

```
b = a;
```

the *value* in `a` is copied into `b`. That value is an object reference, so they now both point to the same object, but **there is no ongoing link between `a` and `b`**. If you then do

```
a = {/*new object*/};
```

that has no effect whatsoever on `b`, because there's no ongoing link between `a` (the variable) and `b` (the variable). `b` still refers to the original object, not the new one.

The same is true of any assignable item, such as an object property or parameter. That's what's happening with `globalVars.Modules.aspect`. `globalFunctions` is grabbing the value (simple assignment semantics, though using destructuring), then `server.js` is replacing that value with a new one.

Here's how that's happening in your code:

```js
// server.js
var globalVars = (function() {
    // globalVars.js
    return { // this is the `exports` object
        Modules: {
            aspect: {},                             // *** That's the `a = {/*original object*/}`
        }
    };
})();
// back in server.js
globalVars.Modules.globalFunctions = (function() {
    // globalFunctions.js
    const { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;          // **** That's the `b = a`
    return { // this is the `exports` object
        getHumanData: function(){
            return "MR. " + aspect.getAspect();
        }
    };
})();
// back in server.js
globalVars.Modules.aspect = (function() {           // *** that's the `a = {/*new object*/}
    return { // this is the `exports` object
        getAspect: function(){
            return "human";
        }
    };
})();
// back in server.js
globalVars.Modules.globalFunctions.getHumanData();  // Fails because the object it's using
                                                    // is the old one, not the new one
```

#### How to fix it

`globalFunctions.js` relies on `aspect.js`, so have it rely on it directly:

```
// In `globalFunctions.js`
const aspect = require("./aspect.js");
    
module.exports.getHumanData = function(){
    return "MR. " + aspect.getAspect();
};
```

Assuming there are no cycles, that'll work.

At a larger level: There may be no reason to have `globalVars.Modules` at all. A module is only loaded once (normally), so rather than `globalVars.Modules`, just have each module directly rely on the module it needs, rather than funnelling it all through a central object. Node.js' module cache is *already* the central object.

If you don't want `globalFunctions.js` to rely on `aspect.js` directly (why not?), then don't copy the `aspect` property from `Modules`, use it as of when you need it:

```
// In `globalFunctions.js`
const {Modules} = require("./globalVars.js");
    
module.exports.getHumanData = function(){
    return "MR. " + Modules.aspect.getAspect();
};
```

That'll work assuming nothing reassigns `Modules` (which nothing seems to in the code you've shown). But again, it makes more sense to rely on `aspect.js` directly if you can.

---

It's kind of fun to note that this is one of the reasons that modern ESM modules don't use simple assignment semantics like CommonJS ones do. ESM wouldn't help your specific thing, because you're using your own `globalVars.Modules` object instead of using the module objects, but it solves a problem that people often had with CommonJS modules which, like your problem, was caused by expecting `b` (an imported value) to be affected when reassigning `a` (the exported value). The issue people would have with CommonJS happened mostly when there were cycles between two modules (circular dependencies, directly or indirectly). ESM solves this by making the imported binding (`b` in my example) a *live binding* to the exported binding (`a` in my example). This is the only place JavaScript has what you could argue is a form of pass-by-reference (references to variables).

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, `var { aspect } = globalVars.Modules;` copies the *current* value of `globalVars.Modules.aspect` to the local variable `aspect`. It's just alternative syntax for `var aspect = globalVars.Modules.aspect`.

If you later change the value of `globalVars.Modules.aspect` to a new object (as opposed to mutating the object that is already there) then the local variable doesn't update.

If you want the most recent value then you need to continue accessing `globalVars.Modules.aspect` whenever you need it.